# VS Code started to selfclose tags like meta, label, input br

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, emmet

Somehow VS code started to selfclose some tags that dont need it in HTML5 syntax, till yesterday it was working perfectly fine but now it looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>forms</title>
  <!-- wiecej info https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp -->
</head>

<body>
  <form action="xxx">
    <label for="username">enter username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" /><br />
    <label for="password">enter password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" /><br />
    <label for="color">pick your color</label>
    <input id="color" type="color" /><br />
    <label for="number">enter number</label>
    <input id="number" type="number" placeholder="enter a number" /><br />
    <!-- <input type="" /> -->
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

when tags like meta or even b> dont need selfclosing br />

Answer (score 0):

It might happen if you either enabled xhtml output profile in Emmet settings or use html/xhtml syntax in VSCode